# In Scala/Playframework, how does "Future" and "Future.map" work under the hood?

Tags: multithreading, scala, events, playframework-2.0, future

The demo codes are from [here](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell)

```
object ProxyController extends Controller {

  def proxy = Action {
    val responseFuture: Future[Response] = WS.url("http://example.com").get()

    val resultFuture: Future[Result] = responseFuture.map { resp =>
      // Create a Result that uses the http status, body, and content-type 
      // from the example.com Response
      Status(resp.status)(resp.body).as(resp.ahcResponse.getContentType)
    }

    Async(resultFuture)
  }

}
```

As I understand, the workflow looks like this:

1. One of the listener threads (threads to process the HTTP request), `T1`, executes the proxy action, running through the code from top to bottom. When it runs at the `WS.url("http://example.com").get()`, `T1` just delegate the Web Request to another thread (worker thread) `W1` and go the the next line. Then `T1` skip the contents of the function passed to the `map` method, since that depends on a non-blocking I/O call that has not yet completed. Once T1 returns the `AsyncResult`, it moves on to process other requests.
2. Later on, the worker thread `W1` finished the Web Request to "http://example.com", then it sends signal to a listener thread `T2`, which may or may not be the same as `T1`. Then `T2` starts to execute the `responseFuture.map` line, and then delegate the task to another worker thread `W2`. Once the task is delegated to `W2`, `T2` moves on to process other requests.
3. Later on, the worker thread `W2` finished creating result (the `responseFuture.map` line), then it sends signal to a listener thread `T3`. And `T3` get the result from `W2` and send this result to the client in a magic way (It looks magic because I've no idea how `T3` knows the original client.. Is it done by closures?)

Is this the real workflow under the hood? If so, will it be too complex and ineffective for the thread communication? If not, what happened under the hood for the codes above? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Close.. there isn't a thread listening for a `Future` to complete though. The code that is executed in `map` just gets re-submitted as another task for the thread pool, and so on.